# Regex in C# acting weird

Tags: c#, regex

I've encountered a problem while working with regex in C#. Namely, the debugger shows correct(IMO) results but when I try to print the results in my application, they are different(and wrong). Code below:

```
Match match2 = Regex.Match("048 A Dream Within A Dream (satur) (123|433) K48", "(.*)(\\((.)*?\\))\\s\\((.)*?\\)\\s.*");
string nick = match2.Groups[1].Value;
string name = match2.Groups[0].Value;
Console.WriteLine("nick - '{0}', name - '{1}'", nick, name);
```

Expected results show up in the debugger, as in following screenshot: [image]

Console shows different(wrong) results:

> nick - '048 A Dream Within A Dream ', name - '048 A Dream Within A
> Dream (satur) (123|433) K48'

How do I fix it? I want the results to be shown exactly as in debugger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the fact that `Groups[0]` is always meant to represent the *whole match*. The first capturing group is in `Groups[1]`. You want:

```
string nick = match2.Groups[2].Value;
string name = match2.Groups[1].Value;
```

The reason it's showing what you expected in the debugger is that you're looking at the *implementation detail* of a field within `GroupCollection`; when it's asked for a group by number, it returns the match if the requested number is 0, or offsets the number by 1 otherwise.

From the documentation for [`GroupCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection.aspx):

> If the match is successful, the first element in the collection contains the Group object that corresponds to the entire match. Each subsequent element represents a captured group, if the regular expression includes capturing groups.

Comment: thank you both for the valuable information and a working solution! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking into `_groups` field, but it's not exactly what is returned as `Groups` property:

[image]

Change your code to use `Groups[1]` and `Groups[2]`:

```
string nick = match2.Groups[2].Value;
string name = match2.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: thank you both for the valuable information and a working solution! :)
I chose Jon's answer as he was the first one to reply - I hope you don't mind.